# pgrep inside bash script not working

Tags: bash, unix, grep

I'm trying to save the `pgrep -f "instance"` output inside a variable in a bash script. For some reason it doesn't work:
here is the code:

```
function check_running() {
  local component_identifier=$1
  local process_check=`get_component_param_value $component_identifier $process_check_col | tr -d '\n'`
  if [ "$process_check" != "n/a" ]; then
    log "process to check: ****""$process_check""****"
    pid=`pgrep -f $process_check`
    log "pid: " $pid
  fi
}
```

I have tried with different ways, in single and double quotes.
Also, neither this works:

```
pid=$(pgrep -f "$process_check")
```

Please note that the process_check variable returns correctly and is definitely working.
I believe the problem is that this field is at the end of the line and may contain a `\n` char, that is why I've added a `tr` in the process_check var.

Any idea?

this is the output of the logs:

```
process to check: ****"instance"****
pid:
```

Comment: Does `ps -ef | grep \"instance\"` show that you do, in fact, have a process running that contains the word "instance" (with the quotes) somewhere in it's command line? I suspect you've got some extra quotes in there, possibly from the output of `get_component_param_value`...

Comment: I tryed with single quotes, no quotes or double quotes and it is always the same.. In any case, the command `pgrep -f "instance"` works perfectly on the server, I'm expecting this will work fine even in command line. If I print the command and there are no extra quotes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way to answer this question:

```
echo `ps -ef | grep "$process_check" | grep -wv 'grep\|vi\|vim'` | awk '{print $2}'
```

I hope other people will find this useful

Answer (score 0):

Well, in my case it didn't like the arguments I was trying to pass.

```
pgrep -f "example" # working
pgrep -f "-f -N example" # not working
```